Oracle Trigger for adding new tables to audit
I'm trying to create a trigger which is firing after creating a new table in a specific schema called "HK".
Background: all tables of schema HK need to be audited for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE actions on it. Also all tables which are created in future.
I created an audit policy before called "changes_on_hk". For that I just take one table of that schema
create audit policy changes_on_hk actions insert, update, delete on hk.TABLE_001;
With this small procedure I put all other tables into this audit policy
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables WHERE upper(owner) = 'HK')
  LOOP
    l_sql_stmt := 'alter audit policy changes_on_hk add actions insert, update, delete on ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

And this is my trigger for future situation when new tables are created in HK schema to have these tables direct in audit
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SYSTEM.CHECK_HK_TABLES_FOR_AUDIT
AFTER CREATE ON SCHEMA
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(1000);
  v_schema_name varchar2(100);
  v_table_name varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  v_schema_name := ora_dict_obj_owner;
  v_table_name := ora_dict_obj_name;
  
  IF v_schema_name = 'HK' THEN
    l_sql_stmt := 'alter audit policy changes_on_hk add actions insert, update, delete on ' || v_schema_name || '.' || v_table_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
    END IF;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER SYSTEM.CHECK_HK_TABLES_FOR_AUDIT ENABLE;

Now I try to create a test table as different user (in this case I take system) in schema HK
CREATE TABLE HK.TEST_DAVID_SYSTEM
(
    column_1 number,
    column_2 varchar2(5)
);

and as user HK in schema HK
CREATE TABLE HK.TEST_DAVID_HK
(
    column_1 number,
    column_2 varchar2(5)
);

After this I look with this SQL, if the new tables are in my audit policy
select upper(table_name) from all_tables where upper(owner) = 'HK'
minus
select upper(object_name) from audit_unified_policies where lower(policy_name) in ('changes_on_hk');

But they're not. Do I miss something?

I've found now this way to server my needs.
I use a after create on database trigger because the on schema trigger looks like that it is just fired when the user is the schema.
As Oracle don't allow to give over audit policy commands direct in trigger I've created a procedure which is executed within a Job in the trigger like on this blog https://dioncho.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/executing-ddl-in-the-ddl-trigger/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SYS.EXEC_AUDIT_STMT(l_sql_stmt in varchar2)
IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SYS.CHECK_HK_TABLES_FOR_AUDIT
AFTER CREATE ON DATABASE
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(1000);
  v_job number;
BEGIN
  IF ora_dict_obj_owner = 'HK' and ora_dict_obj_type = 'TABLE' THEN
    l_sql_stmt := 'alter audit policy changes_on_hk add actions insert, update, delete on ' || ora_dict_obj_owner || '.' || ora_dict_obj_name;
    DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(v_job, 'EXEC_AUDIT_STMT(''' || l_sql_stmt || ''');', sysdate+(1/24/60/60));
  END IF;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER SYS.CHECK_HK_TABLES_FOR_AUDIT ENABLE;

First I tried the job over DBMS_SCHEDULER because DBMS_JOB is the old class. But that job wouldn't like to run. Maybe I investigate a bit in this later.
